# Configuring python interpretor with pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Whenever I am configuring python interpreter, on compiling a pop-up is popping up to edit, modify, or uninstall python ,below is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: which python version is installed on your system? you might want to specify the location of the latest python3.x.exe in interpreters

Comment: well,even on specifying the location,it is showing invalid location

Comment: From your IDE > Select project intepreter > Set to C:\Python35\python.exe
Is it installed on E:\??

Comment: Have you installed python on E:\??

Comment: Cool, hope the path has to be corrected. (Y)

Comment: actually I have 2 versions ,first in in E:\ and other in C but earlier neither of them were working but this time it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Auto Config feature of the IDE looks for it in the PATH set by the user.
Better way to do it is add it in your system variables from where the IDE could pick it up.

For Mac its under the `Library\Frameworks\Python.framework\Versions\X.Y\bin\`

For Windows its mostly under `C:\PythonXY\python.exe`

& For more 'what ifs' you can find it documented [here](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html).